# Play, Previous, and Next button Icon not displayed on volume indicator

Tags: indicator, 14.10

i'm just install Ubuntu 14.10 (fresh install),
and i'm realize that Previous, Play, and Next button icon on the volume indicator are not displayed, the button are there and work, but just not displayed

[image: volume indicator]

what can i do to make the button icon displayed?

Comment: Are they really missing or are they just not displayed. To me it seems like the buttons actually are there, but not displayed. How else would you explain the spaces?

Comment: @the_Seppi You are right, they are just not displayed, the button actually there and work but not displayed, what can i do to make the button displayed?

Comment: Would you add this as an edit to your question so it's clear for everyone?

Comment: @the_Seppi okay i'm just edit my post, hope the problem will be fixed soon, thanks for your suggestion